# Can't write hebrew in lyx

Tags: hebrew

I am using `Lyx` (with `MikTeX`), and now I nead to write documents in Hebrew, but it doesn't work for me. Every time that I tried, I got the warning "File 'cp1255.def' not found".
[image: File 'cp1255.def' not found]

I did a search in Google, and found [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349644/using-lyx-in-windows-w-hebrew-cp1255-def-not-found), that said I need to download the package `babel-hebrew`, so I downloaded babel-hebrew. But there was no installation file, but only a zip file, so I nead to know where to put the file (somewhere in C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3?). I would like to know the exact location, or anyone has another solution for the problem?

Comment: Lyx depends on a working LaTeX distribution to run. How did you install TeX? Did you install MikTeX maybe? The easiest thing to do is to try to install the babel hebrew files using the manager for your TeX distribution. Someone may be able to provide you with more detailed instructions if you edit your question to specify which TeX distribution you are using.

Comment: For Hebrew it’s strongly recommended either `xetex` or `luatex`. The following answer may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617803/cant-export-hebrew-lyx-file-to-pdf/617858#617858 . There is a sample for `luatex` here: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/lua-hebrew.tex (tex), https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/lua-hebrew.pdf (pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the template files from https://github.com/guyru/lyx-hebrew-templates. They properly setup LyX with XeTeX (which is the modern way to get Hebrew support). To use the templates as is, you need to have [Culmus fonts](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/) installed. Alternatively, change the fonts under Documents->Settings->Fonts to something you have installed. See [this blog post](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/21/creating-a-hebrew-document-in-lyx-2-1-with-xetex/) for more details.