# Can't export Hebrew LYX file to PDF

Tags: lyx, hebrew, culmus

I installed LYX by the [official instructions](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew?fbclid=IwAR2mm_bhDi1zeRlhrl26xeGcUESQxFp16ZjQYzFct53tFQxXfvzo5_tFzzY). When I view[ctrl+R] a document which includes **only English** text - a new PDF file open properly, but if the document includes Hebrew letters I get an error (attached as picture).
I had tried to download ['culmus.sty' file](https://math.huji.ac.il/%7Esameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html) and copy to some directories, but it didn't help.
~ The files directories which were mentioned:

- AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\culmus
- AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\tools
- AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\culmus
- C:\Users~myUserName~\culmus\tex\latex\culmus

[image: error output]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would advise you to use lualatex instead of pdflatex for hebrew. Installing and using culmus is quite a pain.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer , how I do so?

Comment: You can find various lualatex examples here on the site, but I'm not a lyx user and can' t tell you how to use them there.

Comment: Apparently, multilingual support in LyX is a bit out of date and it doesn’t take into account the latest developments in `babel` for `xetex` and `luatex`. But may be I’m wrong (in fact, I’d like to be wrong!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, if you write Hebrew documents - you should follow after [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uyx8bpTBy7dsU2R090yqPXkVXBLpGucg/view) guide :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve managed to configure LyX to use `babel` with `lualatex`. The key  point is to bypass the way LyX configures languages and fonts. Here is a set of screenshots (in the 2nd screen the language should read ‘Hebrew’, of course, not ‘Hebreo’).

With the first setting (Font) we avoid loading `luainputenc`, which is strongly discouraged, but added by default by LyX with `luatex`. Note no font is actually selected, but this is the only way I’ve found to get rid of that package.

[image]

The next setting tells LyX not to use any package for languages.

[image]

And now, the real thing by hand.

[image]

**Edit.** If the previous code doesn’t work for you, try with:

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
```